# Ubuntu 13.10 Dell E1705 Wired and Wireless Broken

Tags: networking, 13.10, dell

When installing from a live USB, the wired connection worked.
Upon reboot the wired and wireless do not work now.

`lspci` shows them as:

Wired `BCM4401-b0`

Wirelss `BCM4311 R2`

How can I fix this?

"Edit"
sudo modprobe b44 and the terminal cursor sits there solid. I dont see the typical command line response.

Edit:
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.141+bdcom

### Kernel:  3.11.0-12-generic (i686)

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod......

DKMS: uninstall completed.

---

Deleting module version: 6.30.223.141+bdcom

### completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.11.0-12-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.11.0-12-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.

Do I restart the laptop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please hook up the ethernet and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe b44
```

Your ethernet should now be working and we'll use it to fix your wireless:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and tell us how it's working.

Comment: sudo modprobe b44 and the terminal cursor sits there solid. I dont see the typical command line response.

Comment: Any clues in the log? dmesg | grep b4

Comment: My laptop wont boot now. Trying to re-install now.

Comment: New install of 13.10.  Wired works now.  Software & Updates: Additional Drivers shows the Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-card is not working and shows 2 options:  bcmwl-kernel-source(proprietary) and Do Not Use This Device.  The second radio button is highlighted.  Suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: dmesg | grep b4 shows a BUNCH of stuff.  Im reading a bunch of errors now.

Comment: errors show:  b43/ucode5.fw and b43-open/ucode5.fw not found.  It directs me to a link to DL the correct firmware and carefully read all instructions.

Comment: Followed the following and WIFI works.

12.04 (Precise Pangolin) - 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)

Open a Terminal and if you haven't already done so, update your package list:

sudo apt-get update

If you have a b43 card use the command

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer